# API is working but aws api gateway menu is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

i'm working with aws api for my flask server.
the api endpoint is working, **but the api menu in aws is empty.**

Is there any reason that I can access the api but it's menues and configurations are totally empty in aws.com?

Comment: Did you selected the correct `region`?

Comment: I didn't, now I changed the region and it worked, Thanks!